# How to run a function in meteor reactively?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a function that does some gui-logic, and I need this to run every time meteor updates a template reactively.

I tried putting the code in the Template.myTemplate.helpers, like shown below, but then nothing works at all.

```
Template.ResourceManager.helpers({
        names : function(){
                myFunction();
                return resources.findOne({age : 20}).names;
    }
});
```

Basicly, I need myFunction() to run every time anything changes in *resources*.  I can't find any way to do this.  I've tried looking into autoRun, along with cursor.dependency, but I don't really understand how they work, or how to apply them here.  Any help would be **greatly** appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `cursor.observeChanges` on the `resources` collection.

```
function myFunction(id, fields){
  console.log("something happened on resources", id);
}

var cursor = resources.find();
cursor.observeChanges({
  added:myFunction,
  changed:myFunction,
  removed:myFunction
});
```

https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe_changes